# TeamCity not recognizing calabash-android

Tags: ruby, teamcity, calabash-android

TeamCity not recognizing calabash-android when running tests.

I have following Command Line runner type in build steps that is running Custom script

```
calabash-android run myorg.myapp.android.dev-Signed.apk --format html --out test_report.html --format pretty
```

But running the test fails with Exit code 1 showing this in log

```
[14:17:37]Step 1/1: Run UI Tests (Command Line)
[14:17:38][Step 1/1] Starting: C:\BuildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script2560166106056025753.cmd
[14:17:38][Step 1/1] in directory: C:\BuildAgent\work\8cb09469a30da521
[14:17:38][Step 1/1] 'calabash-android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[14:17:38][Step 1/1] operable program or batch file.
[14:17:38][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
[14:17:38][Step 1/1] Step Run UI Tests (Command Line) failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly says what's happened: `'calabash-android' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`, which means that this program is not in `PATH` variable.

You should [create](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+Build+Parameters) a `env.PATH` variable in your build configuration with the value alike this:

```
%calabash_android_path%%teamcity.agent.jvm.file.separator%bin%teamcity.agent.jvm.path.separator%%env.PATH%
```

where `%calabash_android_path%` must be a variable with full path to the folder with `calabash-android` executable.

Comment: Figured it out, I had it in user path instead of system path.  Moving it to system path solved that issue.  Thanks

Comment: btw, the path you provided looks strange, can you explain it please? Thanks